# How to Perform Action While application closed?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm working on prayer application where user can set alarm for each prayer but now I'm facing problem that how to update alarm's time if user did not open application because prayer time change every 3 , 4 days.

For alarm i'm using "UILocalNotification".

My Question is how can i perform an action while application closed ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple is very specific about what can be run in the background as it doesn't want apps to drain battery unnecessarily. I don't know what your requirements are exactly but these are about your only options for background handling.

1. [Push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)
2. [Background processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

If the prayer times are common for everyone you could set up a server to pull them from periodically.

Comment: My requirement is to find a way, to update " UILocalNotification fireDate " at day end if user not using application.

Answer (score 0):

use eventkit, if you will use, background processing it's has limitation like it's doesn't  have provision of specifying date and time(periodic cycle) when your app will started running even if it's closed.
second option silent push notification has limitation too, like if user doesn't have internet connection. s/he might miss alarm.

best option would be for you eventkit
sample code

```
         - (IBAction)btnAddEvent_touchUpInside:(id)sender {
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[eventDB requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

    myEvent.title     = @"New Event";
    myEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.allDay = YES;

    [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
    if (err == noErr) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                              message:@"Yay!"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"error=%@",err);
    }
}];


  }
```

Comment: i'm bit confuse, if i used  "EKEventStore" than how can i update alarm time. Did EKEvent called when application not running ?

Comment: when you set event by using EKEvent kit, and you open native calendar app of iOS you can see event is registered there, this event will work same as you set alarm for ios native app. it will definitely get called.  there is way you can get all events array registered by your app, modify this event and resave or reregister.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not possible to update the fire date from background. If you are using local notification, then you can do something only after the user enters into the app by swiping the notification/directly launching the app. To be clear, the user has to accept the notification/open the app otherwise NOTHING is called.

Otherwise what you can do is use push notifications. So you can send push notification at any time to the devices which are registered for APNS